# how to bind data to dropdown (data comes from a linq query) using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, linq

how to bind data to dropdown (data comes from a linq query) using jquery?
 following is the html code

```
<div class="col">
    <label id="DLbl" class="control-label">Select</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DListDdl" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Class="selectpicker  form-control" data-live-search="true"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</div>
```

and linq query

```
var DList=(from res in DbContext.transaction

        where res.ProjectId == ProjectId 
       group res by res.Id into res1  
       orderby res1.Key descending
      select new { Id = res1.Key, name = res1.Key.ToString() }).ToList();
```

Comment: If you if you want to do it with ajax (without whole page reload) you shold follow [this manual](http://aspalliance.com/716_Populating_a_DropDownList_using_AJAX_and_ASPNET.4)

Answer (score 0):

Write this code inside the aspx page load.

```
//Even you can fetch the data object from your business logic layer and pass to the dropdown object datasource.
var DList = (from res in DbContext.transaction
                         where res.ProjectId == ProjectId
                         group res by res.Id into res1
                         orderby res1.Key descending
                         select new { Id = res1.Key, name = res1.Key.ToString()
                         }).ToList();

DListDdl.DataSource = DList;
DListDdl.DataTextField = "name";
DListDdl.DataValueField = "Id";
DListDdl.DataBind();
```